# .htaccessのファイル作成について質問です。

Tags: .htaccess

ミラーサイトを正規サイトに.htaccessでリダイレクトしたいのですが
htaccessエディターで作成しましたらSearch Consoleのフォーラムの回答ではダメと言われました。

```
    <Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Redirect permanent https://projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho/ https://kurumajoho.com/
order deny,allow
```

ミラーサイト=https://projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho/
正規のサイト=https://kurumajoho.com/
です。

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho/$ https://kurumajoho.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

これもネットで調べ作成しました。
カスタム制作時に移転用として作成された転送元URLですが/kurumajoho/ディレクトリ部分はいらないのでしょうか？
転送先URLの.htaccessでのリダイレクト

ネットで調べると色んな記述があってわかりません。
正しいhtaccessのファイルを作成したいのです。
素人じみた質問で大変恐縮なのですが回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ご利用になられているApacheのバージョンによって記述の方法が違いますので、Apacheのバージョンを質問文中に追記できますでしょうか？あとダメと言われたということですが、ダメと言われた具体的な内容があれば記述願います。

Comment: keitaro_so様返信ありがとうございます。
Xサーバーですがホームページ関連のウェブサーバーは
apache 2.4.x、nginxになっていました。
ダメと言われた理由は教えていただいていません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Redirect permanentの行は、"Redirect permanent 新ドメイン 移転前のURL"の順なので、”Redirect permanent  https://kurumajoho.com/ https://projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho/”　とすべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: <Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
”Redirect permanent kurumajoho.com projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho”
order deny,allow
Xサーバーの.htaccessの編集の# BEGIN WordPressの上に貼り付けましたが404エラーになりました。
やり方が悪ければ教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じで動きませんか？

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/kurumajoho/$ https://kurumajoho.com/ [R=301,L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

転送元は URL ではなくパスです。

```
Redirect permanent /kurumajoho/ https://kurumajoho.com/
```

Comment: Taichi Yanagiya様返信ありがとうございます。
 <Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Redirect permanent /kurumajoho/ https://kurumajoho.com/
order deny,allow
.htaccessの編集の# BEGIN WordPressの上に貼り付けました。
リダイレクトチェッカーで調べたのですがリダイレクトできませんでした。
やり方が悪いのでしょうか？

Comment: "curl -v -X HEAD https://projects.wordpressrocket.jp/kurumajoho/" で調べると "server: nginx" と出力されます。
.htaccess が利用できないサーバーなのでは？

Comment: Xサーバーはそうなのですか？

他に301リダイレクトの方法があれば教えて頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: .htaccessの編集の画面で# BEGIN WordPressの前文が

＃このファイルはDuplicatorによって2018-10-22 15:24:22に更新されました。元の.htaccessファイルについては、.htaccess.origを参照してください。
＃他のプラグインやリソースがこのファイルに書き込むことに注意してください。上記
のタイムスタンプがファイルシステムの現在のタイムスタンプと異なる場合は、別のリソースがこのファイルを更新しています。
＃デュプリケータは、installer.phpファイルを実行している間、インストールプロセス中に一度だけこのファイルに書き込みます。 ＃BEGIN 

になっていました。これが原因なのでしょうか？
ひょっとして改ざんされていますか？
Duplicatorというプラグインで変更されているみたいですね

元の.htaccessファイルについては、.htaccess.origを参照してください。
とありますが元のファイルはどこにあるのでしょうか？

回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 既存の .htaccess が存在するのですね。フロントが nginx、バックが Apache httpd という構成なのかもしれません。すみませんが、Xサーバー固有の設定については知らないので、回答できません。